# Number of combinations of size $k$ of elements in a multiset with finite multiplicites

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, multisets

Suppose I have 3 types of balls each in varying amounts, e.g. 3 Red (R) balls, 3 Green (G) balls, and 2 Blue (B) balls. How many combinations of size $k, k\leq n$ where $n$ is the total number of balls (in this case 8), can be made?

For example, suppose $k = 2$, then we can make the combinations: RR, RG, RB, GG, GB, and BB of which there are 6. Note that the set RG and GR are the same in my example.

It seems almost like a stars and bars problem, but I don't think it applies here. Is there a closed form solution to this problem or a way to calculate the number of combinations that doesn't involve exhaustively generating every possible $k$-combination?

My ultimate goal is to sum over all $1\leq k\leq n$, if it's easier to calculate that number rather than for a specific $k$, that would be useful to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generating functions](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Elohp/docs/math/2011-228/mit-ocw-generating-func.pdf) which are not difficult to learn at a rudimentary level.

Generating function for $0-3$  red balls = $$ 1+x +x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for $0-3$ green balls = $$  1+x +x^2 +x^3$$

Generating function for $0-2$ blue balls = $$ 1+x +x^2 $$

Next, find the coefficient of $[x^k]$ in the expansion of $$(1+x +x^2 +x^3)^2(1+x+x^2)$$

eg for $k=3$ the [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E3+in+%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2Bx%5E3%29%5E2%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29) is $9$

Finally, you can sum up the answers for $k = 1\; to\; n$

Actually, you can get all the information you need by simply [expanding](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%281%2Bx+%2Bx%5E2+%2Bx%5E3%29%5E2%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29) the generating function at one go, and extracting whatever coefficients you need

Comment: This worked out beautifully. It turns out that one doesn't even need to find in general the coefficient of $[x^k]$, just evaluating the polynomial at $1$ does the trick. Moreover, it follows that simply the product of the number of balls of each color plus one gives you the sum of the coefficients from $k=1$ to $n$. (3+1)(3+1)(2+1) = 48. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, Glad to have been of help ! $\;\;$ ;)